# Modify rule when service crashes

Tags: iptables

I have a iptables rule in PREROUTING that redirects all incoming to a specific port, where a service consumes the data. Is there a dynamic way to determine if the service has crashed and remove the rule?

Comment: what level of responsiveness do you need? How long after the service dies can you wait before pulling the rule.  you could run something out of cron that checks every minute it service is active / alive else pulls the rule.  but worse case service crashes right after check and you have another minute before it is pulled.   Or you can look at something like monit / god to do actions.

Comment: I would want real time removal (that seems improbable though). Another service tries to connect to it and crashes, effectively crashing parts of the system. Monit looks useful. Thanks!